# How to make TabBarView take up the size of its children?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I'm trying to implement a TabBarView which should take up the size of its children. I followed other answers on here and wrapped TabBarView with an Expanded widget. But I end up with the following error if I do that. I tried doing what the error told me and wrapped it with Flexible() but I end up with a different error. Could somebody please help me with this? Thanks in advance!

> ```
> RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints
> are unbounded. When a column is in a parent that does not provide a
> finite height constraint, for example if it is in a vertical
> scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the vertical
> axis. Setting a flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that
> the child is to expand to fill the remaining space in the vertical
> direction. These two directives are mutually exclusive. If a parent is
> to shrink-wrap its child, the child cannot simultaneously expand to
> fit its parent. Consider setting mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min and
> using FlexFit.loose fits for the flexible children (using Flexible
> rather than Expanded). This will allow the flexible children to size
> themselves to less than the infinite remaining space they would
> otherwise be forced to take, and then will cause the RenderFlex to
> shrink-wrap the children rather than expanding to fit the maximum
> constraints provided by the parent.
> ```

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final TextEditingController prefixController = TextEditingController();

  String url = "xyz.com";

  final List<String> myData = [];

  Future<String> makeRequest() async {
    print("Getting data from API...");
    var response = await http
        .get(Uri.encodeFull(url), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

    var extractdata = jsonDecode(response.body);

    String data = extractdata['text'];

    //print(data);

    setState(() {
      myData.add(data);
    });

    print(myData);
  }

  TabController _tabController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(
      length: 2,
      vsync: this,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);
    bool isDesktop = mediaQuery.size.width > 500 ? true : false;

    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF15202b),
        body: LayoutBuilder(builder: (ctx, constraints) {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(32),
              child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 15,
                    ),
                    Container(
                        width: isDesktop ? 500 : mediaQuery.size.width * 1,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border(
                                top: BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.grey),
                                left:
                                    BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.grey),
                                right: BorderSide(
                                    width: 0.5, color: Colors.grey))),
                        child: Bio(ctx: ctx)),
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border(
                                  left: BorderSide(
                                      width: 0.5, color: Colors.grey),
                                  right: BorderSide(
                                      width: 0.5, color: Colors.grey))),
                          width: isDesktop ? 500 : mediaQuery.size.width * 1,
                          child: TabBar(
                              controller: _tabController,
                              tabs: [Tab(text: "Tweets"), Tab(text: "About")]),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child:
                              TabBarView(controller: _tabController, children: [
                            TweetScreen(myData, isDesktop, mediaQuery),
                            About(),
                          ]),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    //Text(myData[0]),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: makeRequest,
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: didn't get your question, can you elaborate more ? or consider sharing an image or a diagram explaining your problem.

Comment: Please share a screenshot of what you want